# .NET HTTP parser

Tags: c#, .net, http, parsing

I am writing an application to sniff some HTTP traffic. I am using WinPcap to access the TCP/IP packets. Is there a library that will help me parse the HTTP messages?

I have implemented a basic parser myself, but I would like something more mature: I keep running into new variations (chunked messages, gzip-compression etc.)

The .NET framework probably have a HTTP parser, but I can't see any way to use it, when the TCP packets do not come from a direct TCP connection.

Comment: I asked a similar question before and couldn't find a solution. Hope this one get answered. It's quite PITA to parse it manually but that's what I've done at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out HttpMachine | https://github.com/bvanderveen/httpmachine

Answer (score 2):

Long shoot, but have you look at [Cassini source code](http://blogs.msdn.com/dmitryr/archive/2005/09/27/474534.aspx)?
I also found [HTML Agility](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) in [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233648/what-is-the-most-useful-net-library-youve-found/233662#233662).

Answer (score 2):

You could create a dummy "http server" and serve your sniffed packets out of it, then you can use .NET's parser (HttpWebResponse or whatever).

Comment: Sure it is, but proper HTTP parsing is difficult. You could try and dig out the needed parts of the .NET parser with reflection, but I wouldn't recommend this approach unless you're really desperate.