# How Create a .NET HttpWebRequest class from a Socket's received byte[]'s

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, httpwebrequest

I have a socket that is receiving HTTP requests.

So I have a raw http request in byte[] form from my socket.

I have to study this request - BUT

Instead of reinventing the wheel - can I *'cast'* this byte array into a System.Net.HttpWebRequest or something similar?

----- UPDATE ---------

So anyway I couldn't find the answer.  By digging a little further though I think it could be done by calling functions in:

**HttpApi.dll**  *I think that the HttpWebRequest uses this dll (winxpsp2)*

the interesting structure is the [HTTP_REQUEST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364545(VS.85).aspx)

```
C++
typedef struct _HTTP_REQUEST {
  ULONG                  Flags;
  HTTP_CONNECTION_ID     ConnectionId;
  HTTP_REQUEST_ID        RequestId;
  HTTP_URL_CONTEXT       UrlContext;
  HTTP_VERSION           Version;
  HTTP_VERB              Verb;
  USHORT                 UnknownVerbLength;
  USHORT                 RawUrlLength;
  PCSTR                  pUnknownVerb;
  PCSTR                  pRawUrl;
  HTTP_COOKED_URL        CookedUrl;
  HTTP_TRANSPORT_ADDRESS Address;
  HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS   Headers;
  ULONGLONG              BytesReceived;
  USHORT                 EntityChunkCount;
  PHTTP_DATA_CHUNK       pEntityChunks;
  HTTP_RAW_CONNECTION_ID RawConnectionId;
  PHTTP_SSL_INFO         pSslInfo;
}HTTP_REQUEST_V1, *PHTTP_REQUEST_V1;
```

I have only just started C# so delving into ??COM?? programming is over my head.
AND looking through the ducumentation, I cant see an 'entry' (by which I mean a simple send bytes-> receieve HTTP_REQUEST).

Anyhoo! if anyone wants to point me in the direction of some nice WINDOWS KERNEL MODE HTTP SERVERS INCLUDING SSL then feel free it would be a great read and something to consider for the future.

Comment: I understand that I cant 'cast' in the traditional/technical sense, but reflecting the HttpWebRequest class and having a poke it seems that the HttpWebRequest is parsed/created from the SerializationInfo of a WebRequest?    its too over my head :/

Comment: Similar questions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318506/converting-raw-http-request-into-httpwebrequest-object - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743794/net-http-parser

Answer (score 15, accepted):

just replace Socket by using **HttpListener**. It parses the HTTP request for you, easily.

Here is an example:

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener(); 
// prefix URL at which the listener will listen
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8080/");
listener.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
while (true)
{
    // the GetContext method blocks while waiting for a request.
    HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
    HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;

    // process the request
    // if you want to process request from multiple clients 
    // concurrently, use ThreadPool to run code following from here
    Console.WriteLine("Client IP " + request.UserHostAddress);

    // in request.InputStream you have the data client sent
    // use context.Response to respond to client
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Have you considered using the [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx) class instead of a socket to receive your incoming HTTP requests?  It will yield [HttpListenerRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistenerrequest.aspx) objects instead of raw data.  I've found these classes useful for simulating a web server.

Answer (score 3):

You can't cast it to `HttpWebRequest` or anything like that. Just throw the `Socket` away and use `HttpWebRequest` instead. Otherwise, you'll have to manually parse the response `byte[]`.